# Not able to config the ssl in wamp socket in my node.js project

Tags: node.js, ssl, autobahn, wamp-protocol

I've used [angular-wamp](https://github.com/voryx/angular-wamp) as a client and [Crossbar](http://crossbar.io/) as a router.
WAMP is perfectly working when i used it without ssl (https).
But when i tried to implement Secure WebSocket it gives error like this in console :

```
WAMP connection closed unreachable { 
 reason: null,
 message: null,
 retry_delay: 2.052066390813223,
 retry_count: 2,
 will_retry: true 
}
```

but in browser it shows ***Congrats!  You're connected to the WAMP server!***

I've used **wss://localhost:8080/ws** as a url in connection.
used this link as a reference https://github.com/crossbario/crossbarexamples

Node.js server is running on 3000 port.

Getting stuck badly, any help would be appreciated.

I've accepted the temporary un-secure certification (usually our self-cert.) for localhost as well as 127.0.0.1 but still got below things.

In browser logs : **Congrats!  You're  connected to the WAMP server!**

I've accepted self signed certification (localhost and 127.0.0.1):

[image: 127.0.0.1]

[image: Localhost]

Answer (score 3):

Please goto https://localhost:8080/ws by your web browser, and accept the temporary un-secure certification (usually our self-cert.), then you can goto your testing web application without this error.

P.S.
Remind that, localhost and 127.0.0.1 both should be accepted independently.

Comment: I've accepted the self signed but still got same response. You can check the attached screenshots  @Chungyan